# Custom System Level Application that still runs when the SystemUsers are switched

Tags: android, kotlin, android-source, customdialog

I want to create a custom application that is stored at a system level and should display information or a floating dialog box all the time (based on the application logic I code) The app should be visible even if the SystemUser switches his profile.

This could be your starting point - https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/UserController.java;l=173?q=Usercontroller&sq=&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject%2Fmain

My Progress -
I've created an application that has this floating widget & is stored as System App.

I've been finding way to do achieve it or modifying the UserSwitchingDialog that system shows and modify it based on my needs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.